# Legend for each part of a piecewise function using PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I'm trying to either include a legend that labels will label all three pieces of the function inside the tikzpicture, or figure out a way to cleanly label the graph outside of the tikzpicture.  I was following a little [guide](https://sites.clas.ufl.edu/gradmath/files/tikz.pdf) for a piecewise function in tikz.  Note that this is a a part of a math test I am making.  Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[10pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{my style/.append style={axis x line=middle, axis y line=
middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, axis equal }}

\setlength{\voffset}{-0.1in}
\setlength{\headsep}{5pt}
\geometry{height=9.1in}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my style, minor tick num=1]
\addplot[domain=-5:-3] {x+3};
\addplot[domain=-3:1] {(4-(1+x)^2)^(1/2)};
\addplot[domain=1:5] {2*x^2/3-8*x/3};

\addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(1,-1)};
\addplot[mark=*,fill=white, only marks] coordinates {(1,-2)(1,0)};
\legend{y=x+3}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: @AndréC What do you mean by that?

Comment: A compilable code should start with `\documentcalss` and end with `\end{document}`. The redundant parts should be included so other users can simply copy and paste your code and compile *immediately*.

Comment: @Ty. Symbol1 has just explained to you what this means. You have added the minimum, you still have to check that it is really compilable, which is not the case. Please give an MWE, see: [Minimum Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimumworking-example-mwe)

Answer (score 2):

Your example still cannot be compiled. I remove unrelated packages and use class `standalone` to show the picture with `tikz` or `pgfplots`.

Please note the package warning and follow the instruction.

```
Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode
(unsuitable tick labels; missing features). 
Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} into your preamble.
```

Manual of `pgfplots` has shown how to add legend and customize legend in sections from `4.9.4 Legends` to `4.9.8`.

### Add legend

You can use `\addlegendentry` or `\legend` or key `legend entries` to add a legend.

With `\addlegendentry`, put every `\addledgendentry` after `\addplot`

```
\addlegendentry{$x+3$}
\addlegendentry{$\bigl(4-(1+x)^2\bigr)^{1/2}$}
\addlegendentry{$2x^2/3-8x/3$}
```

Or simply

```
legend entries={$x+3$, $\bigl(4-(1+x)^2\bigr)^{1/2}$, $2x^2/3-8x/3$}
% or
\legend{$x+3$, $\bigl(4-(1+x)^2\bigr)^{1/2}$, $2x^2/3-8x/3$}
```

### Legend Align and pos

Section 4.9.5 has shown how to change the appearance of the legend.

```
legend cell align=left,
legend pos=outer north east
```

will draw a left aligned legend on outer north east of the axis.

### Legend image

You can customize your own legend image style by `legend image code/.code` (`pgfplots` has provide `line legend`, `empty legend` and `area legend` and so on...)

```
  /pgfplots/line 1/.style={
    legend image code/.code={
      \draw[##1] (0cm, -0.3cm) -- (0.6cm, 0.3cm);
    }
  },
  /pgfplots/line 2/.style={
    legend image code/.code={
      \draw[##1] (0cm, 0cm) arc (180:0:0.3cm);
    }
  },
  /pgfplots/line 3/.style={
    legend image code/.code={
      \draw[##1] plot[smooth] coordinates {
        (0cm, 0cm) (0.2cm, -0.2cm) (0.6cm, 0.6cm)
      };
    }
  },
```

And then apply these styles to your extra entries by `\addlegendimage`, so you must put these entries before every `\addplot`.

```
% extra legend entries
\addlegendimage{line 1}
\addlegendentry{$x+3$}
\addlegendimage{line 2}
\addlegendentry{$\bigl(4-(1+x)^2\bigr)^{1/2}$}
\addlegendimage{line 3}
\addlegendentry{$2x^2/3-8x/3$}
```

### Code and result

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.17,
  my style/.append style={
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$}, axis equal,
    legend cell align=left,
    legend pos=outer north east,
%     empty legend,
  },
  /pgfplots/line 1/.style={
    legend image code/.code={
      \draw[##1] (0cm, -0.3cm) -- (0.6cm, 0.3cm);
    }
  },
  /pgfplots/line 2/.style={
    legend image code/.code={
      \draw[##1] (0cm, 0cm) arc (180:0:0.3cm);
    }
  },
  /pgfplots/line 3/.style={
    legend image code/.code={
      \draw[##1] plot[smooth] coordinates {
        (0cm, 0cm) (0.2cm, -0.2cm) (0.6cm, 0.6cm)
      };
    }
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my style, minor tick num=1]

% extra legend entries
\addlegendimage{line 1}
\addlegendentry{$x+3$}
\addlegendimage{line 2}
\addlegendentry{$\bigl(4-(1+x)^2\bigr)^{1/2}$}
\addlegendimage{line 3}
\addlegendentry{$2x^2/3-8x/3$}

\addplot[domain=-5:-3] {x+3};
\addplot[domain=-3:1] {(4-(1+x)^2)^(1/2)};
\addplot[domain=1:5] {2*x^2/3-8*x/3};
\addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(1,-1)};
\addplot[mark=*,fill=white, only marks] coordinates {(1,-2)(1,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```